# How to remove numeric values as character and resort the string accordng unit number

Tags: r, string, character

I have this string

```
 D = c("0" , "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "41", "42", "43", "44","45", "46","51","52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66")
```

1. If I would to remove those character lower then 30 without transforming the string as numeric, what should I do?
2. If I would like to reorder the string basing on the unit number (meaning that all those with final 1 go before those with final two and so on, such 31, 41, 51, 61, 32, 42 and so on, which should be the opration?

Thanks

Comment: Your input data appears wrong. Is it a vector, missing the commas that separate the entries, or is it a string with too many `"` ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I think it should go fine now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to convert to numeric, `D[D >= 30]` works fine. `>=` works also for character vectors and the sorting depends then on your locale. Check `?Comparison` for more details.

```r
D[D >= "30"]
#[1] "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45" "46" "51" "52" "53" "54" "55" "56" "61" "62" "63" "64" "65" "66"
```

---

For the sorting, this will work (but probably only if you have 2-digit numbers):

```r
str_rev <- stringi::stri_reverse
str_rev(sort(str_rev(D[D >= "30"])))
# [1] "31" "41" "51" "61" "32" "42" "52" "62" "33" "43" "53" "63" "34" "44" "54" "64" "35"
#[18] "45" "55" "65" "36" "46" "56" "66"
```

Or with `str_sub`:

```r
library(stringr)        
D[order(str_sub(D, -1, -1))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if i follow your logic, but how about this solution?

```
D[str_detect(D,"^[12]\\d|0$")]
```

The regex code is basically anything that starts with a 1/2 and followed by a digit or 0. It requires the `stringr` package 9part of `tidyverse`). You could use baseR for it but get use to tidyverse, its better (base R would be `grepl(pattern,string)` )
Otherwise I would def go on `D[D<30]` but that might be cheating

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code

```r
D2 <- enframe(D) %>% arrange(value) %>% filter(value>30) %>% 
mutate(value2=str_extract(value,'\\d$')) %>% 
  arrange(value2) %>% pull(value)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
 [1] "31" "41" "51" "61" "32" "42" "52" "62" "33" "43" "53" "63" "34"
[14] "44" "54" "64" "35" "45" "55" "65" "36" "46" "56" "66"
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) can be done with a comparison operation `!=` that does no number conversion (for number-strings <= 2 digits).

2.) is an ordering operation which internally might rely on a conversion to numeric or an ASCII code table alphabetic sort.

```
D_new <- D[sapply(strsplit(D, ""), \(x) 
  ifelse(length(x) > 1 & x[1] != "1" & x[1] != "2", T, F))]

D_new[order(sapply(strsplit(D_new, ""), \(x) x[2]))]
 [1] "31" "41" "51" "61" "32" "42" "52" "62" "33" "43" "53" "63" "34" "44" "54"
[16] "64" "35" "45" "55" "65" "36" "46" "56" "66"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to extract the second digit is dividing `D` by 10 and use the
remainder. Here is what that can look like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

D <- D[D >= 30]

data.frame(D) |>
  mutate(second_digit = as.numeric(D) %% 10) |>
  arrange(second_digit) |>
  filter(D > 30) |>
  pull(D)
#>  [1] "31" "41" "51" "61" "32" "42" "52" "62" "33" "43" "53" "63" "34" "44" "54"
#> [16] "64" "35" "45" "55" "65" "36" "46" "56" "66"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with regex. Any number 3-9 followed by another number 0-9.

```r
D[grepl("^[3-9][0-9]", D)]
#>  [1] "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45" "46" "51" "52" "53"
#> [16] "54" "55" "56" "61" "62" "63" "64" "65" "66"
```